# How to move a player in unity3D?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I'm doing the roll a ball tutorial and my ball is not moving. I have checked input settings. I have even set a value for speed and even added Time.deltaTime but the body isn't moving

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections; 

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public float speed; 
    private Rigidbody rb; 

    void Start () 
    { 
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 
    } 

    void FixedUpdate () 
    { 
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); 
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical"); 
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical); 
        rb.AddForce (movement * speed); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: using UnityEngine; using System.Collections; public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour { public float speed; private Rigidbody rb; void Start () { rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); } void FixedUpdate () { float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"); float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"); Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical); rb.AddForce (movement * speed); } }

Comment: Please **edit** your question to append the code.

Comment: Did you attach this script to the game object and does it also have a ridged body on it?

Comment: Yes I added the rigidbody component and yes I added the script to the player

Comment: Try using an irrational high value for the speed like 1000 or even higher. I had an issue using AddForce with low values some time ago so I had to use very high values to get my object to move properly. And don't use Time.deltaTime here because it makes the value very small.

Comment: I did it with big values

Comment: Can you try with a different script name and class name. Unity also have **PlayerController** in some parts i belive. That might be a problem. Change it like **myPlayerController**

Comment: @EmreE Thanks. This really worked

Comment: Glad that worked out. I am gonna put it as an answer for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

For further reference for people might encounter same problem.

Unity also have **PlayerController** class, and naming your own class as it will cause problem.

Simply chancing the class and script name to something like **myPlayerController** solved the issue according to OP.